# Keep line spacing, paragraph spacing and other formatting when posting text area data from a form in MVC c#

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor, textarea, http-post

Is there a way I can keep line spacing, paragraph spacing and other formatting when posting text area data from a form in MVC c#

For example, when I post this data:

> Sodales facilisis ligula a porta pellentesque luctus varius tempor felis pharetra conubia >odio curabitur convallis dolor justo magna tristique, imperdiet natoque ultrices.
>
> Leo. Suspendisse habitant pharetra augue dapibus maecenas consequat fermentum nonummy ad >velit. Nulla. Lacinia aliquam, curae;.

An redisplay it, it is displayed like this:

> Sodales facilisis ligula a porta pellentesque luctus varius tempor felis pharetra conubia >odio curabitur convallis dolor justo magna tristique, imperdiet natoque ultrices. Leo. Suspendisse habitant pharetra augue dapibus maecenas consequat fermentum nonummy ad >velit. Nulla. Lacinia aliquam, curae;.

Answer (score 0):

You need a helper which will replace the `"\r\n"` line breaks with a `"<br />\r\n"`.